# Cannot GET /chest-content? How to solve this problem

Tags: node.js

I am struggling with getting a document from the database(MongoDB) by using its ID. I hope you can take a look at my code and give me the solution. Truly appreciate!

```
// NodeJS
router.get('/chest-content/:id', async function(req, res) {
    const target_id = req.params.id;
    var ObjectID = require("mongodb").ObjectID;
    let client = await MongoClient.connect(url);
    let dbo = client.db("HomeFitness");
    const result = await dbo.collection("videos").findOne({ _id: ObjectID(target_id) });
    res.render("chest-content", { model: result });
});

// HTML
<a href="/chest-content?id={{_id}} " style="text-decoration: none"> Image </a>
```

And here is the result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YRZQ.png

Comment: `Cannot GET` means the GET method on that path is not registered. Have you called `app.use("/",router)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the link in `<a>` tag to:

```
<a href="/chest-content/{{_id}}" style="text-decoration: none"> Image </a>
```

##### Explain:

- Cannot GET `/chest-content` means: the client tries to send the request to `/chest-content` URI (with the query `id`) but it cannot find any URI like that. In the server, what you have is `/chest-content/:id`, which will match `/chest-content/someid`.

See Express documentation about `Route parameters` [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const result = await dbo.collection("videos").findOne({ _id: target_id });
```

Comment: I tried but unfortunately it didn't work.